# Select ID with most quantities of records in the table

Tags: sql, t-sql

Players

```
UserID   Achievement
001      Warrior
001      Scout  
003      Golden
004      Camper
004      Scout 
004      Sniper
005      Camper
001      Sneaky
004      Sneaky
```

I need to select **UserID** that have biggest quantity of achievements (biggest quantity records) in table for one UserID, I have tried next one query but looks like my DB dsnt support LIMIT so isnt work :/

```
SELECT CompanyID, COUNT(OfficeLocation) CountOfficeLocation
FROM EntitySite
GROUP BY CompanyID
ORDER BY CountOfficeLocation DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Seems you've been reading the wrong RDBMS' documentation. Every RDBMS uses a different dialect of SQL and it's important you read articles, tutorials and documentation for the one you are using.

Comment: The database vendor name is secured so I cant get that info I just need to select what I noted in my question -.-

Comment: And my question isnt only about limit so its unfair close..

Comment: I didn't say change the RDBMS you are using, I just said that taking any old SQL and trying to use it in the RDBMS you are using won't work if that SQL is the wrong dialect. As for your latter comment, the problem you make your question appear to be able is that `LIMIT` isn't working, and that is explained in the dupe. If that isn't what you're question is about then [edit] it to with your corrected attempt using valid T-SQL and explain why that doesn't work.